# How to simplify comparing?

Tags: java, sorting, stream, compare

I do have list like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(24);
    list.add(12);
    list.add(0);
    list.add(36);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(99);
```

I want to sort it ascendig, but 0 has to always be on the last one. Is there any way to simplify it?

```
   List<Integer> collect = list.stream()
            .sorted((a,b) -> b.compareTo(a))
            .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.valueOf(0).equals(a) ? 1 : -1)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(24, 12, 0, 36, 1, 99);
List<Integer> sorted = list.stream()
.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a == 0 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : a))
.toList();
System.out.println(sorted);
```

Seems to work; prints `[1, 12, 24, 36, 99, 0]`.

The one downside is that it won't do the right thing if literally the maximum integer value (which is `2147483647`) is in your list, in which case it'll sort the 0s amongst them instead of after them. If that is a problem, nothing is going to look significantly shorter than what you did.

NB: Your code appears to sort **descending**. In which case the 0 would already sort at the end unless you have negative numbers. If that's what you want and 'ascending' was a typo, you'd have to use MIN_VALUE instead, and reverse the comparator (tack `.reverse()` t the end).

Answer (score 0):

You can process in the same `sorted`:

```
List<Integer> collect = list.stream()
                        .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1 == 0 ? 1 : (o2 == 0 ? -1 : o1.compareTo(o2)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

May be introducing variables for the comparators and comparing the boolean if an int equals to zero might simplify or at least make it readable

```
Comparator<Integer> natural  = Comparator.naturalOrder();
Comparator<Integer> zeroLast = Comparator.comparing(i -> i.equals(0));

List<Integer> collect = list.stream()
                            .sorted(natural)
                            .sorted(zeroLast)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```